# Workflow Setting a Date field problem

Tags: workflow

I have a workflow rule setup to populate an inactivity date field, it seems like it should work, but it hasn't set the field for the last 2 weeks (since it was created). Am I missing something here?

The field is a Date field called Inactivity_Date__c

The formula is:

```
IF( Reported_Application_Stage__c="Withdraw" , DATEVALUE(Withdraw_Date__c),
    IF(Reported_Application_Stage__c="Ineligible" , Ineligible_Date__c,
        IF(Reported_Application_Stage__c="Purge" , Purge_Date__c,
            IF(Reported_Application_Stage__c="Reject" ,  Deny_Date__c ,
                IF(Reported_Application_Stage__c="Defer" , Defer_Date__c,null)))))
```

Comment: Is Reported Application Stage a picklist?

Comment: Reported Application Stage is a formula field

Comment: @mikesalty - A formula will not trigger a workflow rule. The record has to be directly updated in order to trigger the workflow rule. Just in case you are expecting the formula to trigger the workflow rule

Comment: Eric, you should make your comment into an answer as it is the correct answer. You might also add to your answer how the OP can go about setting up the workflow rule to trigger.

Comment: @Eric The Rule Criteria is this: `OR(ISCHANGED(Status__c),ISCHANGED(Application_Decision__c))` so it's not triggered on the Formula field `Reported_Application_Stage__c` it's merely evaluating that field to determine the associated value.

Comment: Instead of defaulting to `null`, try making the default a known other date. This will indicate the rule is firing, and just not finding a match. If it's still null, I guess confirm the rule is Active?

Comment: @JeremyNottingham, I did as you suggested and the rule is firing, it's just populating as the generic date I set no matter what though.

Comment: Can you post your formula for the "Reported_Application_Stage__c"?

Comment: Sounds like the problem is with your formula field not matching any of the choices displayed. You might try using `CONTAINS()` instead of `=`, but also confirm that the formula is returning the value you expect.

Comment: Actually, I think I may have this fixed now, I just sat on an application and changed it over and over again looking for inconsistent behavior. It turns out that if both the Status field and the Application Decision field are changed in the same edit it would not fire, but if only one was changed it would fire. So I changed the rule criteria to be `OR(OR(ISCHANGED(Status__c),ISCHANGED(Application_Decision__c)),AND(ISCHANGED(Status__c),ISCHANGED(Application_Decision__c)))` and it seems to be working. Why would that behavior change?

Comment: I just tested the OR on 2 fields similar to above and it worked when one or both changed with your initial criteria, are you sure it isn't failing on record creation? The ISCHANGED will not evalulate to true if it's a new record.

Comment: That's ok though, because the field will never be updated upon creation, it's a date field that relies on negative outcomes of interaction with the contact. It needs to go through at least 2 states before it gets there.